# Using .gitignore files in Vercel

Tags: git, next.js, gitignore, vercel

I have a Next.js project. I want to push it to GitHub and link it to Vercel. However, there are files in .gitignore that I need Vercel to see. Instead of adding all that data into my environment file, I am looking for another way to hide these files from GitHub but make visible to Vercel. Any suggestions?

Comment: Q: Have you tried checking the files in manually, e.g. `git add --force`?

Comment: In that case, won't my file be visible on GitHub. I want either to create a different workflow for Vercel or manually be able to include that file into the Vercel directory. I do not want to commit the file to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while trying to hide a `.pem` file in production.

If you're trying to hide a file of a similar nature, such as a certificate (like myself), this is what I did to solve it:

```
project-name/
├── app/
│   ├── ...
├── .../
├── .../
└── private.pem
```

I needed to use the `private.pem` as certification in my code:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const credentials = fs.readFileSync('./private.pem');
// ...
```

I discovered that with vercel CLI you can manually add files as environment variables.

```bash
npm i vercel
```

```bash
vercel env add MY_PRIVATE_FILE production < private.pem
```

**Refactored code**:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

let credentials: Buffer | string;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    credentials = process.env.MY_PRIVATE_FILE!
} else {
    credentials = fs.readFileSync('./private.pem');
}
```

This should work with any private text-type files (`.txt`, etc.)